# Twitter REST API - how to check if an app has certain permission?

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitter-rest-api

Before attempting to write to a user's timeline, I would want to check if an app has write access. How do I check this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response to API requests with a valid access token will have a header named `X-Access-Level`. You can look for the value `read-write` there. Ideally, you will make an API request to`account/verify_credentials` node for this purpose.